# How to add element of a List of List and generate a new List

Tags: java, arraylist, logic

I have some data which is stored in `List<List<String>>` so to get the data I am using this method

```
private static void finalResult(List<List<String>> resultList) {
    for (List<String> listOFResults : resultList) {
        if(listOFResults.get(0).equals("v1")){
            System.out.println("Vehicle is :: "+listOFResults);         
        }
    }
}
```

my output is like this

```
Vehicle is :: [v1, route1, 1.4, destination1]
Vehicle is :: [v1, route2, 2.3, destination1]
Vehicle is :: [v1, route3, 1.2, destination2]
Vehicle is :: [v1, route4, 3.4, destination2]
```

my query is to add index value 2 `i.e 1.4,2.3,1.2,3.4` but the addition has to be in

```
`route1 + route4` = 1.4 + 3.4
```

and after addition I want to store the values of both list in a common List
like

```
 value is :: [v1,route1,destination1,route4,destination2,4.8];
 value is :: [v1,route2,destination1,route4,destination2,5.7];
 value is :: [v1,route3,destination2,route4,destination1,4.6];
```

here I have 3 possible ways to reach my destination here I am filtering for my vehicle 1. Now what I have in my output is my route deatils and time taken to travel. I want to add the 2 routes to compare which can be faster to cover both destination. So possible ways can be Route1 +Route4,Route2+Route4 and Route3+Route4

how to achieve this.

Comment: you can use addAll() method. additionally you can use Streams instead and try to concat both lists and then collect them in one

Comment: can you provide some demo code for explanation .

Comment: Why is this an instance of `List<String>` instead of a well defined POJO ? This would be cleaner... and by the way, your request is not really clear. What are you trying to do exactly ?

Comment: give your resulted output with expected full output.

Comment: @AxelH here I have 3 possible ways to reach my destination here I am filtering for my vehicle 1. Now what I have in my output is my route deatils and time taken to travel. I want to add the 2 routes to compare which can be faster to cover both destination. So possible ways can be Route1 +Route4,Route2+Route4 and Route3+Route4.

Comment: Not really clearer for me, what is the problem in that feature ? And why did your `println` have a "_Vehicule is ::_" and not your output ?

Comment: problem is that I am looking for a solution to add listOFResults[0 ]with listOFResults[4] inside that if condition, or any other way to achive this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending if my assumptions on your question are right, here is a possible solution:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> a1 = Arrays.asList("v1", "route1", "1.4", "destination1");
    List<String> a2 = Arrays.asList("v1", "route2", "2.3", "destination1");
    List<String> a3 = Arrays.asList("v2", "route2", "3.0", "destinationx");
    List<String> a4 = Arrays.asList("v1", "route3", "1.2", "destination2");
    List<String> a5 = Arrays.asList("v1", "route4", "3.4", "destination2");
    List<List<String>> all = List.of(a1, a2, a3, a4, a5);
    List<String> str = all.stream().filter(l -> "v1".equals(l.get(0)))
            .map(l -> {
                double v = Double.parseDouble(l.get(2)) + Double.parseDouble(a5.get(2));
                return String.format("%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%1.1f", l.get(0), l.get(1), l.get(3), "route4", a5.get(3), v);
            })
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    str.forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

This prints out the following:

```
v1,route1,destination1,route4,destination2,4.8
v1,route2,destination1,route4,destination2,5.7
v1,route3,destination2,route4,destination2,4.6
v1,route4,destination2,route4,destination2,6.8
```

What this code does?

1. it filters the "v1" elements
2. performs the calculation and creates the string in the format you specified
3. collects these strings into a list

But honestly: the best thing would be to create proper Plain Old Java Objects (POJO) with the fields corresponding to your data model. Shuffling strings around like what I did is never the best idea.

Comment: This is working .. thanks, can you provide some link for creating POJO. or what POJO is.

Comment: @VipulSingh: here is a link on POJOs on Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_old_Java_object .

Comment: this portion is a small section from from project where I have to find minimum time taken to travel 2 different point on a map.so all these data is coming from user end and here I have to match and find which is the best route.

Comment: so here I was getting time to travel one route with a certain vehicle and similarly will get for other vehicle. so I have to sort for each vehicle and add two routes to get total time to travel which can be queried for minimum time from all.